# See other tag but not his own

Tags: c#, arraylist, unity-game-engine

Is it possible to call all the objects in an array? Or is using the number the only way?

```
public void Update()
{
    Targetting ge = (Targetting)target.GetComponent("Targetting");
    enemies = ge.targets;

    float attackDistanceP = Vector3.Distance(target.transform.position, transform.position);

    foreach (Transform enemy in enemies)
    {
        float enemyDistance = Vector3.Distance(enemy.transform.position, transform.position);
        print(enemyDistance);
    }

    Debug.DrawLine(transform.position, waypointPosition, Color.black);

    if (attackDistanceP < 8)
        disableNow = true;

    if (attackDistanceP > 8)
        disableNow = false;

}
```

I want to call all of the objects in the enemies[] array. So that all of the enemies can see each other. But I don't want to them to see themselfs. Im using the GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag to fill the array in an other script.

Comment: What is it that you are storing in the tags?

Comment: I am using List<Transform>enemies;

Comment: I do not fully understand the context of your problem so I won't be providing you with a full answer or a code snippet, but you could try checking if somehow the enemies ID or some other unique identifier equals his own while calling all the objects in `enemies[]`. Hope that helped you a bit.

Comment: I've got an array wich loops trough every object with the tag == "Enemy". This function is in a script on an Enemy. I have three enemies in my scene, so I get three distance variables wich is the distance between the enemy with the script, and the other enemies. But it also returns a distance value of the enemy wich holds te script. So what I want is that it ignores his own tag so that only 2 values return. I edited the above script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some premature optimization for you:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;

public Transform trans;
Targetting ge;

void Start() {
    trans = transform;
    ge = target.GetComponent<Targetting>();
}

void Update () {
    enemies = ge.targets;

    float attackDistanceP = (target.trans.position - trans.position).sqrMagnitude; // save a square root

    foreach(Transform enemy in enemies){
        if (enemy == trans) continue; // skip me

        float enemyDistance = (enemy.trans.position - trans.position).sqrMagnitude; // save a square root
        print(enemyDistance);
    }

    Debug.DrawLine (trans.position, waypointPosition, Color.black);

    if(attackDistanceP < 64)
        disableNow = true;

    if(attackDistanceP > 64)
        disableNow = false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach(Transform enemy in enemies){
    if (enemy == this.transform) continue; // skip me

    float enemyDistance = Vector3.Distance(enemy.transform.position, transform.position);
    print(enemyDistance);
}
```

Comment: An optimization tip: Don't call GetComponent every frame.  You should assign that to a variable in your Start() method.  You should also store the value of this.transform (which is a property that uses GetComponent behind the scenes), because that lookup can get expensive too.

Comment: Thanks mate :) I will try this when I have the time and I will let you know if it works!